# hiding layout but keeping text in page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

suppose that i have html like this

```
<span class='hide'>
   nothing to comment please be good to each other
</span>
```

style

```
.hide{
   /*visibility:hidden;*/
   display:none;
   width:100px;
   height:auto;
}
```

if I use css such as `display:none or visibility:hidden` it's hide all(layout and text) I want to keep text and hiding only layout. is there a way to archived this case ? sincerely thank for your kindly help ...

Comment: What do you mean by "hiding the layout"?

Comment: hidding <span class="hide"> but i want to keep its text

Comment: Why not just remove the `.hide` class from the `span`?

Comment: Or if the span has its own styling, remove them, so that it would seem that the span isn't there and only the text will remain.

Answer (score -2):

Just use toggleClass and create one class that is bare, and one class with all the layout you want

```
<span class='hide' id='comment'>
   nothing to comment please be good to each other
</span>


$("#comment").toggleClass("oldClass newClass");

.oldClass {
  <!--bare formatting-->
}

.newClass{
  <!--fancy formatting-->
}
```